# CSV saves on wrong location

Tags: vba, excel

My code is saving in Local/temporary somewhere - It's supposed to save on Desktop, AND if it already exists, ask before overwriting. Can you help me?

```
Sub Opgave8()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Pth As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Pth = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Set sh = Sheets.Add

    For i = 2 To 18288
        If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
            sh.Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    sh.Move
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=Pth & "\AdminExport.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        .Close False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Do
        n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
        If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
            s = s & n
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = x + 1

    UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

Comment: *Local/temporary somewhere* doesn't exist on my machine. Where specifically is it on yours?

Comment: Users/XXX/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Desktop/AdminExport.CSV    Which seems to be a folder called 'Desktop', and not the desktop it self :)

Comment: I could be wrong here, but shouldn't `ActiveWorkbook.Path` instead be `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` ? Alternatively, `ThisWorkbook.path` uses the path of the workbook with the code in it, not the "currently active" one.

Comment: Well, you could be wrong or right, i am very unsure of this code to be honest. I'm going to try it, and write back in 5 min :)

Comment: @Jiggles32 `Application.ActiveWorkbook` is just fully-qualifying `ActiveWorkbook` - both are one and the same (there are no namespaces in VBA). Same as `MsgBox` vs `VBA.Interaction.MsgBox` or `VBA.MsgBox` or `Interaction.MsgBox`.

Comment: If it helps guys, i see that the file is being named "Desktop\AdminExport.csv"

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, i changed it! :)

Comment: But are you able to help me with it though Mathieu? :-)

Comment: I asked the question 2 times before this one, but noone was able to fix it.

Comment: Well, one option would be to force the path, rather than making it dynamic, but it depends what you need. Or a half-way dynamic and non-dynamic way `Pth = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"`

Comment: It needs to be dynamic, as its supposed to get send to other people, where it should also save on their desktop :) If possible..

Comment: The only thing I see that will cause the file to save in the wrong folder is if the activeworkbook is in the wrong place. try `msgbox pth` somewhere in the code and see if it is the correct path. When you have `sh.move` that sheet becomes the active sheet, but it still does not change the value of `Pth`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Environ$("USERPROFILE")` to create a default desktop save path, then create a simple message box with YesNo option as the code shows:

```
Sub Opgave8()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Pth As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Create default desktop path using windows user id
    user_id = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
    ' Create full path
    file_name$ = "\AdminExport.csv"
    Pth = user_id & "\Desktop" & file_name

    Set sh = Sheets.Add

    For i = 2 To 18288
        If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
            sh.Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    sh.Move

    If Dir(Pth, vbArchive) <> vbNullString Then
        overwrite_question = MsgBox("File already exist, do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo)
    End If

    If overwrite_question = vbYes Then
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Pth, FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Close False
        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Do
        n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
        If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
            s = s & n
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = x + 1

    UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

Comment: While valid 99% of the time, `C:\Users` is making too many assumptions for my taste. I'd go with `path = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & filename` for a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you @MathieuGuindon, that's new for me!

Comment: Cheers everybody, thanks for the help. My only problem now is, that the data is so weird when being pasted into the CSV file.. Gonna make a new question with that

Comment: USERPROFILE - What am i supposed to write there, since its different userprofiles? :-) 
I will mark your questions as acceptable, how do it do it?? :)

Comment: Mathieu, it gives me error in If Dir(Pth, vbArchive) <> vbNullString Then

Comment: You dont need to change `user_id = Environ$("USERPROFILE")` and just tested the line `If Dir(Pth, vbArchive) <> vbNullString Then` it works for me, what kind of error its showing?